# Select second dropdown based on first dropdown using Angular 4

Tags: angular, angular-material

I have two dropdowns that I populate with data from the server. The first dropdown contains a state, and the second one contains city. Like if I select one state name only cities in that state should show in 2nd drop down using Angular 4.

```
<mat-tab-group>
                <mat-tab label="Basic Info">
                    <ng-template mat-tab-label>
                        <div fxLayout="center center">
                            <mat-icon style="font-size: 16px; line-height: 18px">gps_fixed</mat-icon>
                           State
                        </div>                           
                    </ng-template><br /><br /><br /><br />
                    <div class="ui fluid container" fusePerfectScrollbar>
                        <div class="content">
                            <mat-form-field>
                                <mat-select placeholder="State" [(ngModel)]="selectedValue" name="state" (change)="dropdownchange($event.target.value)">
                                  <mat-option>None</mat-option>
                                  <mat-option *ngFor="let state of states" [value]="state">{{state}}</mat-option>
                                </mat-select>
                              </mat-form-field><br />
                              <h3>You selected: {{selectedValue}}</h3>
                        </div>
                    </div>
                </mat-tab>
                <mat-tab label="Location">
                    <ng-template mat-tab-label>
                        <div fxLayout="center center">
                            <mat-icon style="font-size: 16px; line-height: 18px">location_on</mat-icon>
                            City
                        </div>
                    </ng-template>
                    <div class="ui fluid container" fusePerfectScrollbar>
                        <div class="ui fluid container" fusePerfectScrollbar>
                            <div class="content">
                                <mat-form-field>
                                    <mat-select placeholder="City">
                                      <mat-option>None</mat-option>
                                      <mat-option *ngFor="let cities of city" [value]="state">{{cities}}</mat-option>
                                    </mat-select>
                                  </mat-form-field><br />

                            </div>
                        </div>
                    </div>
                </mat-tab>
   </mat-tab-group>
```

Comment: i hope this will help you https://plnkr.co/edit/ctWfT7rnWw2RaSW063TJ?p=preview

Comment: i want to use it in angular material

Answer (score 7, accepted):

app.component.ts

```
import { Component } from '@angular/core';

@Component({
  selector: 'my-app',
  templateUrl: './app.component.html',
  styleUrls: ['./app.component.css']
})
export class AppComponent {
  private map = new Map<string, string[]>([
    ['Poland', ['Warszawa', 'Krakow']],
    ['USA', ['New York', 'Austin']],
  ])

  country: string;
  city: string;

  get countries(): string[] {
    return Array.from(this.map.keys());
  }

  get cities(): string[] | undefined {
    return this.map.get(this.country);
  }

}
```

app.component.html

```
<select [(ngModel)]="country">
  <option *ngFor="let country of countries" [value]="country"> {{ country }} </option>
</select>

<select *ngIf="country" [(ngModel)]="city" [value]="city">
  <option *ngFor="let city of cities"> {{ city }} </option>
</select>
```

[Live demo](https://stackblitz.com/edit/dropdown-based-on-dropdown)

In your case all you need to change from the example above is to  populate the country/cities map with the data from your server.

Comment: can u please use angular material for this

Comment: just change `<select>` to `<mat-select>` and `<option>` to `<mat-option>`.

Comment: i tried that but after selecting 1st dropdown 2nd dropdown is not showing

Comment: add `[value]` binding to `<mat-option> `

Answer (score 0):

You should add an click event into your State's dropbox like

```
<mat-option *ngFor="let state of states" (click)="getCities(state)" [value]="state">{{state}}</mat-option>
```

Then add a function like `getCities(state:string)` into your .ts file and fill the second dropbox content with this function like

```
public cities : string[];
getCities(state:string) {
 this.cities = []; // empty the array first.
 this.cities.push(CITY LIST);
}
```

In this way as soon as a state selected , it's cities will load inside the second dropbox.

Hope it helps.

Comment: What if the user does change the option using keyboard interaction ? You might want to bind the `getCities(state)` to `change` event and not to `click`.

Comment: you can use (change) instead of (click)