# How to pass selected dropdown value to a component

Tags: angular

**I am novice to Angular.**

I am following this accepted answer.
[Select second dropdown based on first dropdown using Angular 4](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/49771116/select-second-dropdown-based-on-first-dropdown-using-angular-4)

I created **dropdown based on dropdown** as follows -

```
    <select [(ngModel)]="country">
      <option *ngFor="let country of countries" [value]="country"> {{ country }} </option>
    </select>

    <select *ngIf="country" [(ngModel)]="city" [value]="city">
      <option *ngFor="let city of cities" [value]="city"> {{ city }} </option>
    </select>
```

```
    export class AppComponent {
      private map = new Map<string, string[]>([
        ['Poland', ['Warszawa', 'Krakow']],
        ['USA', ['New York', 'Austin']],
      ])

      country: string;
      city: string;

      get countries(): string[] {
        return Array.from(this.map.keys());
      }

      get cities(): string[] | undefined {
        return this.map.get(this.country);
      }

    }
```

Now I want to -

pass the **Selected Value** to the component.

I tried passing static value like this -

```
    <app-render country="USA" city="Austin"></app-render>
```

*this works fine*

So, to pass selected value, I tried like this -

```
    <app-render [country]="country" [city]="city"></app-render>
```

**Please Help/Guide.**

Comment: this is not how you use a select tag : `<select *ngIf="country" [(ngModel)]="city" [value]="city">
  <option *ngFor="let city of cities"> {{ city }} </option>
</select>`

Comment: the [value]="city" should be on options

Comment: ```    <select *ngIf="country" [(ngModel)]="city" [value]="city">
        <option *ngFor="let city of cities"> {{ city }} </option>
    </select>``` tried this.

Comment: do you mean  to set default value or preload selected value ?

Comment: the value selected  will be  updated at variable `city` since you used `[(ngModel)]="city"`

Comment: I want to get 'country' as well as 'city' value. Country & city values are already mapped in .ts file.

Comment: I tried to change ```[(ngModel)]="cityy"``` then ```{{cityy.value}}``` / ```{{cityy.name}}``` but didn't work.

Comment: @JoelJoseph Could you please help ? how to pass this value in component & receive in component?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Thank you everyone for help/input. Below code works -

```
<select [(ngModel)]="input-country">
  <option *ngFor="let country of countries" [value]="country"> {{ country }}</option>
</select>

<select *ngIf="country" [(ngModel)]="input-city" >
  <option *ngFor="let city of cities" [value]="city"> {{ city }} </option>
</select>
```

and then

```
<div *ngIf="city">
    <app-render [country]="country" [city]="city"></app-render>
</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this

```
<option *ngFor="let city of cities" [ngValue]="city"> {{ city }} </option>
```

Answer (score 0):

```
<select [(ngModel)]="input-country">
  <option *ngFor="let country of countries" [value]="country"> {{ country }}</option>
</select>

<select *ngIf="country" [(ngModel)]="input-city" >
  <option *ngFor="let city of cities" [value]="city"> {{ city }} </option>
</select>
```

And then

```
<app-render [country]="input-country" [city]="input-city"></app-render>
```

Comment: ```<app-render [country]="input-country" [city]="input-city"></app-render>``` **didn't work**. but ```<p>Selected city: {{city}}</p>``` **worked**.

Comment: I have below code in .ts ```   @Input()
  public country: string;

  @Input()
  public city: string;

  ngOnInit() { 
    console.log('Country', this.country);   
    console.log('City', this.city);  
  }```

Comment: It seems component is already loaded, its **not loading** after selecting values.  so in *my.component.ts* file, these values are *NaN*.